# How would I find the projection of a vector onto a line, given the equation of the line in the form $y = mx + b$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the equation of a line in the form $y = mx + b$.  I also have a vector $a$.

How would I find the projection of $a$ onto the the line?

Comment: Did you mean projection of $a$ onto the direction of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the slope of the line. It is $m$, or $\frac{m}{1}$.

Therefore, the vector representation of the line can be seen as $<1, m>$

I assume the vector representation of the line is $<a_x, a_y>$

Therefore, the vector projection is:

$$\frac{<a_x, a_y> * <1, m>}{\left(||<1,m>||\right)^2}*<1, m> = \frac{a_x + ma_y}{1+m^2}*<1, m>$$

$$= <\frac{a_x + ma_y}{1+m^2}, \frac{m(a_x + ma_y)}{1+m^2}>$$

Comment if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

From the line equation, we find the slope to be:

$$\tan\alpha=\frac{dy}{dx}=m$$

So 
$$\sin\alpha=\frac{m}{\sqrt{m^2+1}},\cos\alpha=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}$$

The unit tangent vector $\vec{t}$ is given by:

$$\vec{t}=(\cos\alpha,sin\alpha)$$

The project of vector a onto this line is equal to $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{t}=a_x \cos\alpha +a_y \sin\alpha$.

Comment: @copper.hat. Thanks! I corrected it.